# Link to StackExchange main site

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice if sites had a link to StackExchange's main site. I find myself regularly editing my address bar's contents just to do something websites used to do as a unwritten rule.

Comment: Does the link "More Stack Exchange communities" in the dropdown work for you?

Comment: There is no link to the parent site.

Comment: Those words are linked to http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: I see. I hadn't noticed that. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, web sites would include a link back to the home page - the SE sites are all different, stackexchange.com is not the "homepage".

Comment: The sites are directly related, just like help.foo.com and foo.com

Answer (score 1):

The text "More StackExchange communities" is a link to https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: outdated - there is no such text on the page as of now (2016)